# Rails 4: Alternative to strings when setting "type" / "status" attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've run into this situation many times, where I need to store something like a status persay, so it would be something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  INCOMPLETE = 'Incomplete'
  IN_PROGRESS = 'In progress'
  SHIPPED = 'Shipped'
  CANCELLED = 'Cancelled'
  ...
end
```

Order would have a `status` attribute, and when creating an order I would just use `collection_select` with `[INCOMPLETE, IN_PROGRESS, SHIPPED, CANCELLED]` as the options.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this without using hardcoded strings, like using a `Status` association or some sort of PORO? I feel like this would be a bit brittle, like if someone changed the `INCOMPLETE = 'Incomplete'` to `INCOMPLETE = 'Incompletezzzzz'` then all the statuses of my existing records would not match.

Comment: What version of Rails? I ask because Rails 4.1 has an `enum` attribute type that suits your purpose pretty well: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum

Comment: (And for other versions of Rails, there's the [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) gem.)

Comment: Wow nice. I'm on 4.0.0. I guess I can upgrade to the latest

Comment: The attribute `type` is reserved and should not be used (except for Single Table Inheritance cases). Ruby on Rails relies on this `type` attribute to find from which Class comes from the record from the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use another model in this situation, something like `OrderStatus`:

```
class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :internal_reference, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :orders

  def translated(locale = :en)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.order_status.#{self.internal_reference}", locale: locale, default: self.internal_reference)
  end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  validates :order_status_id, presence: true
```

And the records will look like this:

```
OrderStatus.first
# => OrderStatus id: 1, internal_reference: canceled
Order.first
# => Order id: 3, order_status_id: 1 # etc.
```

In your views, it could be:

```
order.order_status.translated(I18n.locale) 
# looks for activerecord.attributes.order_status.canceled
# if nothing found, returns the internal_reference, here it would return `'canceled'`
```

This configuration is better than just constants :

- You can create as many statuses as you want,
- You can translate them directly (using `internal_reference` as key for I18n),
- The statuses can be tested either if they are in english, french or whatever (thanks to `internal_reference`,
- You can create statuses directly in your app, without rebooting it,
- You can set an attribute, like `status_code` and makes ranges (kind of like HTTP requests statuses) and group them (ex: `if status_code > 100`)

You can also add an boolean attribute `cant_be_deleted` to prevent from deleting Statuses used in the code.

You might think it is overkill to do so, but I guarantee that the day you will want to `translate` / `add` / `remove` / `change` your Statuses, it will be much easier with Models rather than Constants. Trust me, I worked for an Online shop, handling Carts, Orders and Products, I know how painful it is to change from constants to models, everywhere in your already existing code ;-)

Comment: Thanks! And you nailed it, I do have to translate them eventually. What exactly is `internal_reference` though? Is that a special attribute?

Comment: Yes, it is a special attribute kind of acting like an ID, but for humans: It must be **unique**, must be **present**, and can be used directly in your code, whatever the Locale is (allows you to do calls like `Order.includes(:order_status).where(order_statuses: { internal_reference: :canceled }).first` instead of `Order.where(status: Order::CANCELED).first`)

Answer (score 1):

I think enumerize gem can help

You can write your code like this

```
class Order < ActiveRecord:Base
  extend Enumerize

  enumerize :status, in: [:incomplete, :in_progress, :shipped, :cancelled]
end
```

It also works perfectly with I18n.

https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize